# Function naming conventions

Tags: function, naming-conventions

I am writing a library, so, I want its functions to be named as clearly and cleverly as possible. Currently, I use the following principles:

1. Self-explanatory names: a
   function getName() will tell the
   developer what it returns as well as
   setAddress(), isMale(), etc.
2. Short: a function name must be as
   short as possible so that it's
   simple to type as well as easy to
   remember. A function
   getNumberOfPagesInTheBook() is not
   good, something like
   getBookPageCount() is better.
3. Use of prefixes: I always use
   prefixes in the functions such as
   getName(), setName(), hasHair(),
   isBlond(), etc.

I'm interested in knowing if there's something I'm missing. Also, can you think of some other prefixes other than is, has, get and set?

Comment: This is language-dependent to some degree, since different languages often have different naming/coding conventions.

Comment: getters and setters can be an indication of poor design, if you have too many of them.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: Interesting! Curious to know why and what would be better approach then? (This is about getters and setters)

Comment: If you need many get/set functions, it is often an indication that your class is simply a "record" with no real behaviour.

Comment: @anon (Jan 2 '10 at 11:34) I don't see your point. The question is "What are good naming conventions?". Your answer seems to be a half-voiced disapproval of things like Data Access Objects?

Comment: @Tower did you gain more thought about the question? I have a similar problem, although it is objective c. So if a method return a value and also perform an action, how do you name it ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154814/objective-c-naming-convention-for-method-performs-an-action-and-returns-a-value

Answer (score 110, accepted):

One of the more universal, yet simple rules is: Function names should be verbs if the function changes the state of the program, and nouns if they're used to return a certain value.

Comment: so that means getter functions are all named wrong?... ie getSomeValue();

Comment: @timh Accessors are a bit of a special case, they usually return properties of an object, something you'd just use property access syntax for in C# or AS3.

Comment: @timh yes they are wrong thats why C# fixed theirs with get;set property

Comment: This isn't a good rule in languages with named closures and computed properties. A better rule for languages with those features is to always name functions as verbs or predicates. You have to think about what the function will look like when stored as a closure. A noun won't make sense; that gives the impression that it's the result of invocation.

Comment: @Jessy I think there is no contradiction: a function that can be returned with a closure, is a function that can change state by definition. So such functions should be named as verbs.

Comment: Can you explain this rule? In my understanding it contradicts the guideline of the Clean Code book, which states "Methods should have verb or verb phrase names" [p25], which I personally like to adhere to.

Comment: A verb means action, functions do things.  Using verbs for all function names is reasonable.

Comment: Using a noun function name does not make sense to me ever. `getHorse()` returns `horse`. `horse` is a variable, it's not something you can call. It could be an object or a string, but not a function. It could also be `makeHorse`, `editHorse`, `doAnythingWithHorse`, but never just `horse()`. `Horse` could be a class so we could make an instance of horse like `new Horse()` but that's not calling a function.

Answer (score 19):

One more important thing to do when writing a library is to use the same word to describe the same action every time. Don't write a function named **getName** in one class and another function named **retrieveNumber** in another class.

Comment: I typically use `get` when it gets the data locally from class variable and or has a calculation (e.g `circle.getArea()`), and then I use `retrieve` when it must get this data from the outside, (e.g from database: `db.retrieveUserById(123)`

Comment: @DavidCallanan, how it the method of retrieval relevant to the caller?

Comment: @ThaJay looking at this two years later, it probably isn't relevant to the caller where the data comes, and I would probably use get everywhere.

Comment: @ThaJay The same as why this is considered something every programmer should know: https://colin-scott.github.io/personal_website/research/interactive_latency.html Knowing to call getArea in the main loop of your game but that retrieveArea may not be what you want is a helpful hint. I don't see a downside to providing that hint

Comment: In front-end, we use get for local and fetch for remote data. So in a way I agree and do see how this distinction would be relevant. Also, a getter is synchronous and a fetcher is not.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a great resource advising the same as [Carl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991324/function-naming-conventions/1991341#1991341): *[Strive for Fluent Usage](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#strive-for-fluent-usage)*

> **Name functions and methods according to their side-effects**
>
> - Those without side-effects should read as noun phrases, e.g. `x.distance(to: y)`, `i.successor()`.
> - Those with side-effects should read as imperative verb phrases, e.g.,
>   `print(x)`, `x.sort()`, `x.append(y)`.

Comment: I find this a pretty bad convention, because so many words are both noun and verb. Even in the example: You can `distance` yourself from something, and obtain a `print` using some `sort` of paper. In practice I would have no clue which of `x.view()`, `x.set()`, or `x.route()` may have a side-effect.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at

- [Naming Conventions for .NET / C#
  Projects](http://www.akadia.com/services/naming_conventions.html)
- [Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Other prefixes? Possibly "isa", though that is only applicable in some situations.

Some languages can communicate "get" and/or "set" with other constructs (specifically, in Common Lisp you can make (setf (get* ...) blah) do the same as what you would've wanted (set* ... blah) do).

Answer (score 0):

**If there is a universal rule, I think it should be to be consistent.**

There is also the "on" prefix, which is widely used when dealing with events (i.e. Java Android: [`onViewCreated`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated(android.view.View,%20android.os.Bundle))). Some other prefixes or short and/or generic verbs (such as has, get and set) widely used are:

- [can](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#canScrollHorizontally(int))
- [put / post](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

I prefer using nouns for simple getters when there is very little logic involved (i.e. properties) but I would use the "get" prefix for complex actions:

```
func center() {
   return (a + b) / 2
}
```

However, in some languages where using explicitly the "get" prefix is widely extended (i.e. Android - Java), the common practice is using some verb such as "compute" (i.e. [`computeVerticalScrollOffset()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#computeVerticalScrollOffset()))

Furthermore, in some languages (e.g. [swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)) you can also use property setters so you don't really use the "set" prefix:

```
var x: X {
  get {
    return foo(x)
  }
  set {
    x = bar(newValue)
  }
}

// Set x
x = y
```

And finally, there are many widely used constructions such as [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/instanceof), [`indexOf`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp), ...

Answer (score 0):

#### Pro get/set

When a class has many methods, it is better to use verb prefixes, such as get/set, to distinguish methods from each other.

PHP example:

```
$foo->setText('Hello world!');
$foo->prependText('So. ');
$foo->appendText(' And welcome');
$x = $foo->getText();
```

By the way, in Hungarian notation prefixes go with a small letter and will not detract from keyword.

#### Counter get/set

When you need only two methods, it is easier to use the same noun in the context of using parameters.

jQuery  example:

```
$('.foo').html();                //get
$('.foo').html('Hello world!'); //set
```

---

#### Examples

For functions and static methods with arrays as parameters I use the following rule:

If changes should occur only at run time:

```
setFoo($arr); // Replace/delete all properties, i.e. if some elements are not passed, the corresponding properties will get empty values.
setFoo([]); // Delete all properties
setFoo(); // Set all properties by default
delFoo($arr); // Delete specified properties
addFoo($arr); // Add/replace specified properties
```

If changes will be made forever (in DB or files):

```
deleteFoo(...); // Delete specified properties
insertFoo(...); // Add specified properties
replaceFoo(...); // Add or replace specified properties
updateFoo(...); // Update specified properties
```

For both cases:

```
$arr = getFoo(); // Get all properties    
$val = getFoo($level1, $level2, ...); // You can obtain the value of the given level, placing the list of arguments
or
$val=getFoo()[$level1][$level2];
```