# Objective C naming convention for method performs an action and returns a value

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, methods, naming-conventions, naming

I have a method that performs an action and returns a value. For example  from the input number it will update class's input history, then generate and return an input record. So how do I name this method?

I think even C has this problem, e.g. **fopen** function does open a file and return a handler. But with Objective C convention it seems difficult to name the method.

From apple document for cocoa [name convention](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html) and also from this article [cocoa with love](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/method-names-in-objective-c.html) They both said "*If a method performs an action the first word should indicate that action*" and "*If a method returns a value the first word normally indicates what will be returned*"

So if I name something like `callRecordFromNumber:(NSString*) number`, it only indicates the returned value, not the action it performs. If I name something like `updateCallRecordFromNumber:(NSString *) number`, it only indicate the action, not the returned value.

BTW, I do consider separate it into 2 methods, but the thing is the new record is generated alongside with the action is performed. The code like this: creating a new one if not exists, then update history record. And the actual code has several types of histories (say, missed call history, rejected call history, total history), and record is generated and updated for its own history. So separating it into 2 methods will introduce too many duplicated codes. Seems not a good option here.

```
Record *record = totalHistory[number];
if (record !=nil ) return record;
record = [[Record alloc] initWithNumber:number];
record.type = [self callType:number];
totalHistory[number] = record;
switch (record.type) {
    case -1: /*missed call*/ {
    missedHistory[number] = record;
    break; }
    case 0: /*normall call*/ {
    acceptedHistory[number] = record;
    break; }
    case 1: /*rejected call*/ {
    rejectedHistory[number] = record;
    break; }
    ...
}
return record.
```

---- Update ----

Following 2 discussions are helpful too.

[How to name a method that both performs a task and returns a boolean as a status?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/244630/how-to-name-a-method-that-both-performs-a-task-and-returns-a-boolean-as-a-status)

[Naming functions that retrieve a value](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/198165/naming-functions-that-retrieve-a-value)

Now I am using the method name like this, **valueByPerformed**..., e.g. recordByUpdatedCallHistoryFrom:

Wordy :( I wish there was a better name！

---- update ----

[swift 3.0 naming guideline](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#naming), e.g. [Verbs vs Nouns Naming Convention](http://www.appcoda.com/swift3-changes/), like sort vs sorted gave me some new thought about this question. Now I do think **valueByPerformed** is probably a good name :D

Comment: Why can't it be two separate methods? Ever heard of the single responsibility principle? A method that is hard to name is usually doing too much.

Comment: Thanks. I did think about that. Updated my question.

Comment: That code doesn't always update your history dictionary. It's more of an "addRecordWithNumberToHistoryIfItDoesntAlreadyExist".

Comment: Then what about the returned value ?

Comment: Thanks for that. I also updated my question, adding more explanations for my code. So I had to say your answer (which I did consider before) may not be right.

Comment: I still don't see any reason why it couldn't be two separate methods. Post the real code or else we can't be sure. As for your original question, Apple provides _guidelines_ for naming which you may not always be able to stick to. However, it should be a red flag whenever a method becomes too complicated to appropriately name.

Comment: I do agree with you that it should be a red flag whenever a method becomes too complicated to appropriately name. I updated my question, post as much code as I could, containing the same logic as real code.

Comment: You have a totalHistory dictionary that you can use to get your record back in a separate method.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're letting the limitations of some other code prevent you from writing clean code. Don't let it. What exactly is stopping you from doing something like this...?

```
NSNumber *myID = @(123);
[self updateCallRecordWithID:myID];
Record *myRecord = [self callRecordWithID:myID];

- (void)updateCallRecordWithID:(NSNumber *)recordID {
    history[number] = [[Record alloc] initWithNumber:recordID];
}

- (Record *)callRecordWithID:(NSNumber *)recordID {
    return history[recordID];
}
```

Comment: Hi, updated my question again, add the code (simplified version). So I am not sure 2 methods is good here.